# github pages custom domain - can't point AWS route 53 domain at it

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, github-pages

I am trying to point my AWS hosted domain at my github pages.

In the Route 53 Console, I created the following records per the github pages instructions:

```
Type A:

185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153

Type AAAA

2606:50c0:8000::153
2606:50c0:8001::153
2606:50c0:8002::153
2606:50c0:8003::153
```

If I create these, then try to add my domain to my github pages, then I get the following error
[Github pages error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynbkl.png)

In AWS, there are NS and SOA records that AWS creates as default (I can't delete, only change):

```
NS:

ns-1929.awsdns-49.co.uk.
ns-1160.awsdns-17.org.
ns-548.awsdns-04.net.
ns-266.awsdns-33.com.

SOA
ns-773.awsdns-32.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

**Question:

```
I am assuming the problem is with the two records above? What should I change these to?
Or am I doing something else wrong?**
```

FYI I was following this article, but it gives no mention to the NS and SOA records.

Thanks

https://medium.com/@benwiz/how-to-deploy-github-pages-with-aws-route-53-registered-custom-domain-and-force-https-bbea801e5ea3

Comment: Do you actually have a hosted zone for `www.yourdomain.com` or just for `yourdomain.com`? They are very different things! Please follow and work through https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site and do what fits your actual goal, e.g. apex vs subdomain. Your records indicate apex domain but your screenshot shows `www` sudomain.

Comment: @luk2302 I have a hosted zone for brownphotographic.com in AWS. When I try entering brownphotographic.com I also get an error. 
Both brownphotographic.com and its alternate name are improperly configured
Domain's DNS record could not be retrieved. For more information, see documentation (InvalidDNSError).

Answer (score 0):

For apex domain, we need 2 records:

1. A Record pointing to Github Pages IP

```
Type: A

Name: your-domain.com

Value:
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

2. CNAME record pointing to your account

```
Type: CNAME

Name: www.your-domain.com

Value: your-github-account-name.github.io
```